# Скачивание файла с сервера

Tags: python, django

Хочу, чтобы у пользователя была возможность скачать файл с сайта, находящийся в папке `uploads`. Не знаю, как это правильно реализовать. Нашел в интернете ответ - [Как в django отдать медиа файл?](https://toster.ru/q/208755). Какой при этом способе должен быть `views.py` и `urls.py`?

Comment: Django не занимается раздачей файлов, для этого есть nginx

Comment: @andreymal иногда удобно без него.

Comment: тем не менее отдавать файл как вложение это ж жесть..
я бы редиректом отдал